# Multiple bonds in Lewis structure

Tags: chemfig, chemistry

I've been using the `chemfig` package for drawing Lewis structures but have run into an issue in which I need to show multiple bonds between two atoms in Lewis dot notation as show below.

[image: Multiple bonds between carbon atoms]

The code I have so far is:

```
\lewis{0:,H} \lewis{0:,C} \lewis{4:,C} \lewis{4:,H}
```

which produces

[image: Lewis structure with chemfig package]

Is this structure possible with the `chemfig` or other package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that `\lewis` introduced some negative spaces that need to be compensated. And one can cheat with `\vphantom`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\lewis{0:,H}~\lewis{0:,C}~\lewis{0:,\vphantom{C}}~~\lewis{0:4:,C}~\lewis{4:,H}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: “ It seems that `\lewis` introduced some negative spaces” there is also `\Lewis` which doesn't ignore its bounding box.

Comment: @clemens Thanks, I didn't know that!