# Triple bond in Chemfig

Tags: chemfig, chemistry

I have built the following resonance structures, but I would like to represent bonded electrons with dots and not dashes. In the case of a double bond I can use `\:` and get something like `X::Y`, but in the case of a triple bond what can I do to get something like `X⋮⋮Y`? :(

I hope you can help me.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
            
    \setchemfig{atom style={scale=.85},arrow coeff=.85,atom sep=2.5em}
    \schemestart%
    \chemname{%
        \chemleft[ \chemfig{%
            \charge{180=\:}{S}~C-\charge{0=\:,90=\:,270=\:}{N}%
        } \chemright]\chemmove{\node[] at (2pt,6pt) {\footnotesize $-$};}}%
    {Estructura 1}%
    \arrow(.mid east--.mid west){<=>}%
    \chemname{%
        \chemleft[ \chemfig{%
            \charge{90=\:,270=\:}{S}=C=\charge{90=\:,270=\:}{N}%
        } \chemright]\chemmove{\node[] at (2pt,6pt) {\footnotesize $-$};}}%
    {Estructura 2}%
    \arrow(.mid east--.mid west){<=>}%
    \chemname{%
        \chemleft[ \chemfig{%
            \charge{90=\:,180=\:,270=\:}{S}-C~\charge{0=\:}{N}%
        } \chemright]\chemmove{\node[] at (2pt,6pt) {\footnotesize $-$};}}%
    {Estructura 3}%
    \schemestop
            
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I placed single dots in different directions to form the triple bond. Thanks!

`\chemname{%
\chemleft[ \chemfig{%
\charge{180=\:,0=\.,30=\.,330=\.}{S}~\charge{0=\.,154=\.,180=\.,206=\.}{C}-\charge{0=\:,90=\:,270=\:,180=\.}{N}%
} \chemright]\chemmove{\node[] at (2pt,6pt) {\footnotesize $-$};}}%
{Estructura 1}%`

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/443995/multiple-bonds-in-lewis-structure

Comment: Can you please complete your Latex code, so it will work when we copy, paste and compile it? Thanks.

Comment: Or just add the preamble, \begin+\end document ...

Answer (score 1):

do you want something like this?

```
\begin{document}
 
\setchemfig{atom style={scale=.85},arrow coeff=.85,atom sep=2.5em}
\schemestart%
    \chemleft[ 
    \chemfig{\charge{180=\:}{S}\vdots \vdots C-\charge{0=\:,90=\:,270=\:}{N}} \chemright]
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

[image]

... Or this, maybe?

```
\begin{document}
\setchemfig{atom style={scale=.85},arrow coeff=.85,atom sep=2.5em}
\schemestart%
\chemleft[
\chemfig{\charge{180=\:,35=\.,0=\.,325=\.}{S}\,\,\, \charge{180=\.,150=\.,210=\.,0=\.}{C}\,\,\,\charge{180=\.,0=\:,90=\:,270=\:}{N}} \chemright]
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]